# solving the wave 1-d equation with python and animate

Tags: python, pde

I'm trying to solve the 1-d wave equation, and I coding the program for numerical computing solutions and animating, saving data in the file. I don't know how to fix the error and finally get the working code.

```
u_tt = a**2 * u_xx + f(x,t)
```

It is necessary for the program to solve equations when entering both an additional function and with non-zero initial and boundary conditions, with graphic visualization and saving data to a file.

So I attach my code (Python 3.9), and error message:

```python
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import time
import glob


def sol(I, V, f, a, L, C, T, U_0, U_L, dt, user_func = None):
    """
    solver for wave equation
    u_tt = a**2*u_xx + f(x,t) (0,L) where u=0 for
    x=0,L, for t in (0,T].
    :param I:
    :param V:
    :param f:
    :param a:
    :param L:
    :param C:
    :param T:
    :param U_0:
    :param U_L:
    :param dt:
    :param user_func:
    :return:
    """

    nt = int(round(T / dt))
    t = np.linspace(0, nt * dt, nt + 1)  # array for time points
    dx = dt * a / float(C)
    nx = int(round(L / dx))
    x = np.linspace(0, L, nx + 1)  # array for coord points
    q = a ** 2
    C2 = (dt / dx) ** 2
    dt2 = dt * dt

    # --- checking f(x,t) ---
    if f is None or f == 0:
        f = lambda x, t: 0  

    # --- check the initial conds dU(x,0)/dt ---
    if V is None or V == 0:
        V = lambda x: 0

    # boundary conds
    if U_0 is not None:
        if isinstance(U_0, (float, int)) and U_0 == 0:
            U_0 = lambda t: 0
    if U_L is not None:
        if isinstance(U_L, (float, int)) and U_L == 0:
            U_L = lambda t: 0

    # ---  allocate memory  ---
    u = np.zeros(nx + 1)  
    u_n = np.zeros(nx + 1)  
    u_nm = np.zeros(nx + 1)  

    # --- valid indexing check ---
    Ix = range(0, nx + 1)
    It = range(0, nt + 1)

    # --- set the boundary conds ---
    for i in range(0, nx + 1):
        u_n[i] = I(x[i])

    if user_func is not None:
        user_func(u_n, x, t, 0)

    # --- finite difference step ---
    for i in Ix[1:-1]:
        u[i] = u_n[i] + dt * V(x[i]) + 0.5 * C2 * (0.5 * (q[i] + q[i + 1]) * (u_n[i + 1] - u_n[i]) -
               0.5 * (q[i] + q[i - 1]) * (u_n[i] - u_n[i - 1])) + 0.5 * dt2 * f(x[i], t[0])

    i = Ix[0]
    if U_0 is None:
        # set the boundary conds (x=0: i-1 -> i+1  u[i-1]=u[i+1]
        # where du/dn = 0, on x=L: i+1 -> i-1  u[i+1]=u[i-1])
        ip1 = i + 1
        im1 = ip1  # i-1 -> i+1
        u[i] = u_n[i] + dt * V(x[i]) + \
               0.5 * C2 * (0.5 * (q[i] + q[ip1]) * (u_n[ip1] - u_n[i]) - 0.5 * (q[i] + q[im1])
                           * (u_n[i] - u_n[im1])) + 0.5 * dt2 * f(x[i], t[0])
    else:
        u[i] = U_0(dt)

    i = Ix[-1]
    if U_L is None:
        im1 = i - 1
        ip1 = im1  # i+1 -> i-1
        u[i] = u_n[i] + dt * V(x[i]) + \
               0.5 * C2 * (0.5 * (q[i] + q[ip1]) * (u_n[ip1] - u_n[i]) - 0.5 * (q[i] + q[im1]) * (u_n[i] - u_n[im1])) + \
               0.5 * dt2 * f(x[i], t[0])
    else:
        u[i] = U_L(dt)

    if user_func is not None:
        user_func(u, x, t, 1)

    # update data
    u_nm, u_n, u = u_n, u, u_nm

    # --- time looping ---
    for n in It[1:-1]:
        # update all inner points
        for i in Ix[1:-1]:
            u[i] = - u_nm[i] + 2 * u_n[i] + \
                   C2 * (0.5 * (q[i] + q[i + 1]) * (u_n[i + 1] - u_n[i]) -
                         0.5 * (q[i] + q[i - 1]) * (u_n[i] - u_n[i - 1])) + dt2 * f(x[i], t[n])

        #  --- set boundary conds ---
        i = Ix[0]
        if U_0 is None:
            # set the boundary conds
            # x=0: i-1 -> i+1  u[i-1]=u[i+1] where du/dn=0
            # x=L: i+1 -> i-1  u[i+1]=u[i-1] where du/dn=0
            ip1 = i + 1
            im1 = ip1
            u[i] = - u_nm[i] + 2 * u_n[i] + \
                   C2 * (0.5 * (q[i] + q[ip1]) * (u_n[ip1] - u_n[i]) - 0.5 * (q[i] + q[im1]) * (u_n[i] - u_n[im1])) + \
                   dt2 * f(x[i], t[n])
        else:
            u[i] = U_0(t[n + 1])

        i = Ix[-1]
        if U_L is None:
            im1 = i - 1
            ip1 = im1
            u[i] = - u_nm[i] + 2 * u_n[i] + \
                   C2 * (0.5 * (q[i] + q[ip1]) * (u_n[ip1] - u_n[i]) - 0.5 * (q[i] + q[im1]) * (u_n[i] - u_n[im1])) + \
                   dt2 * f(x[i], t[n])
        else:
            u[i] = U_L(t[n + 1])

        if user_func is not None:
            if user_func(u, x, t, n + 1):
                break

        u_nm, u_n, u = u_n, u, u_nm

    return u, x, t



# --- here function for return functions ---
# return func(x)
def func(x):
    """
    :param x:
    :return:
    """

    return # expression

# start simulate and animate or visualisation and savin the data from file
def simulate(
        I, V, f, a, L, C, T, U_0, U_L, dt,  # params
        umin, umax,  # amplitude
        animate = True,  # animate or not?
        solver_func = sol,  # call the solver
        mode = 'plotter',  # mode: plotting the graphic or saving to file
):
   # code for visualization and simulate
   ...........
    # start simulate
    solver_func(I, V, f, a, L, C, T, U_0, U_L, dt, user_func)

    return 0

def task( ):
    '''
    test tasking for solver and my problem
    :return:
    '''

    I
    L = 1
    a = 1
    C = 0.85
    T = 1
    dt = 0.05
    U_0, U_L, V, f
    umax = 2
    umin = -umax

    simulate(I, V, f, a, L, C, T, U_0, U_L, dt, umax, umin, animate = True, solver_func = sol, mode = 'plotter',)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    task()
```

And I get the same error:

```
File "C:\\LR2-rep\wave_eq_1d.py", line 102, in sol
u[i] = u_n[i] + dt * V(x[i]) + 0.5 * C2 * (0.5 * (q[i] + q[i + 1]) * (u_n[i + 1] - u_n[i]) -
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

I understand the meaning of the error, but I do not understand how it can be fixed, and for almost two weeks I have not been able to write a program ... I ask for help with solving this problem! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I would recommend that just before the line that gives you the `TypeError`, print out all the variables that you are trying to subscript (i.e. all the variables with a `[i]` or `[i+1]` after them. That should show you which of those variables isn't an array.

Comment: @jjramsey

I printed out all variables, and the debugger shows, that all variables are array. So, but it prints only the first element on the array.

Comment: You should easily be able to print all the elements of an array, like this: `print(f"u = {u}")`, `print(f"u_n = {u_n}")`, `print(f"q = {q}")`, etc. How are you printing out the variables?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with an emphasis on *minimal*. There is no reason to include e.g. code that animates the solution if it is code that generates the solution which is throwing an error. There is no good reason to post hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: @jjramsey

I use into the loop:

    for i in Ix[1:-1]:
        print(u)
        print(u_n)
        print(q)
        u[i] = u_n[i] + dt * V(x[i]) + 0.5 * C2 * (0.5 * (q[i] + q[i + 1]) * (u_n[i + 1] - u_n[i]) -
               0.5 * (q[i] + q[i - 1]) * (u_n[i] - u_n[i - 1])) + 0.5 * dt2 * f(x[i], t[0])

Now, I see that q is not an array or list, but I don't know how to rewrite the finite difference method, because "q" for every inner node of mesh is changed...

Comment: @JohnColeman

Sorry, I'd edit the code and remove some parts of them.